# Anyway to add notice in Automake's make check?

Tags: testing, makefile, autotools, automake, notice

I am refining my `Makefile.am` file now. The script would skip some non-essential test if the environment does not match the requirement.  I want to **notify the user that some tests are skipped**.

I have tried to add some `.PHONY` target to `TESTS` array. Such as:

```
if HAVE_PYTHON
# something to do with python
else #HAVE_PYTHON
TESTS += skip-python-test
.PHONY: skip-python-test
skip-python-test:
    @echo "Python is not detected"
    @echo "Will skip some test"
endif #HAVE_PYTHON
```

However, the `test-driver` **checks** the existence of those target regardless `.PHONY` setting. The `test-suite.log` will be like this:

```
FAIL: skip-python-test
======================

./test-driver: line 95: ./skip-python-test: No such file or directory
```

How to refine my `Makefile.am`? Or what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `check-local` target conditionally — see [Extending Automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html) for the details. Basically you can make it conditional so that you'd end up with:

```
if HAVE_PYTHON
  …
else
  check-local: skip-python-test
endif

skip-python-test:
    @echo "Python not detected, will skip some tests."
```

and that should work; alternatively you can do that in `configure.ac` so that the user can notice right away that they should install more dependencies to have full test coverage.